# isdigit function for BCPL

Tags: operating-system, bcpl

I am currently programming in BCPL for an OS course and wanted to write a simple `is_digit()` function for validation in a program of mine.

A code snippet of my current code follows:

```
let is_digit(n) be {
  if ((n >= '0') /\ (n <= '9')) then 
    resultis true;
}
```

I am aware that BCPL has no notion of types, but how would I be able to accomplish this sort of thing in the language?

Passing in a number yields a `false` result instead of the expected `true`.

Answer (score 2):

is_digit() is a function returning a value, rather than a routine, so should use = VALOF rather than BE. Otherwise, the code is OK.

```
let is_digit(n) = valof {
    .....
    resultis true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions that return values should be using `valof` rather than `be`, the latter (a routine rather than a function) can be *called* as a function but the return value you get back from it will be undefined<sup>(a)</sup>.

In addition, you should ensure you return a valid value for every code path. At the moment, a non-digit will not execute a `RESULTIS` statement, and I'm not *entirely* certain what happens in that case (so best to be safe).

That means something like this is what you're after, keeping in mind there can be implementation variations, such as `&` and `/\` for `and`, or `{...}` and `$(...$)` for the block delimiters - I've used the ones documented in Martin's latest manual:

```
LET is_digit(n) = VALOF {
    RESULTIS (n >= '0') & (n <= '9')
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Since Martin Richards is still doing stuff with BCPL, [this manual](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emr10/bcplman.pdf) may help in any future questions (or see his [home page](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emr10/) for a large selection of goodies).